# How to use routerLinkActive with a function, without calling it multiple times?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

I want to use routerLinkActive with a function, but the function is being called indefinetly,

```
<a routerLink="/home"  target="_self" [routerLinkActive]="checkActive('home') ? 'active': ''">
```

in .ts file

```
checkActive(url : string){
   var curLocation = window.location.pathname;
   var loc = (curLocation.split('/')[2] || '');
   if(url == loc){
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Here loc is basically a check if a particular word exists in a url.
Neither does the active class is added, also the function is being called indefinitely. Please suggest some solution.

Comment: You should try adding router link active conditionally.

Comment: For what exactly do you want to use that function? I'm a little bit confused. RouterLinkActive will do the stuff for you?